# .htaccess works but wont let me access blog index.php in sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

been playing about with mod rewrite on the .htacces file.. ive managed to take of the the .html at the end my files for the url which looks a lot better, problem im getting now is that i have a blog folder which contains all my blog files including the index.php file.. problem is it wont load this page up now.. the code im using for the re-write is..

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

the error code im getting it this

You don't have permission to access /MyFiles/katie2/blog/.html on this server.

when it should load

/myfiles/katie2/blog/index.php

any help guys would be great..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Good luck!

Comment: @AC88 No worries. Glad it could help! It's something I've used myself in the past, so it was just a simple cut and paste job. Please consider ticking it as the answer!

Comment: Will do got to wait 4 min though :S defo getting a tick